# Excel VBA pass file path to routine to open Outlook

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have a few routines that I'm trying to get to work together.  The first 2 find the outlook.exe file on the user's machine and I would like the 3rd to use that file to open Outlook if it isn't already running.  The issue I'm having is being able to pass that file's path to the 3rd routine.  Here's my code.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
    Sub GetSubFolders()

        Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
        Dim f As Folder, sf As Folder
        Dim myFile As File

        On Error Resume Next

        Set f = fso.GetFolder("C:\Program Files\")

        For Each myFile In f
        Next

        For Each sf In f.SubFolders
            Call Recursive(sf)
        Next

        Set f = fso.GetFolder("C:\Program Files (x86)\")

        For Each myFile In f
        Next

        For Each sf In f.SubFolders
            Call Recursive(sf)
        Next

    End Sub
    Sub Recursive(sf As Folder)
        Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
        Dim f, nsf As Folder
        Dim myFile As File
        Dim s As String
        Dim ofile As String

        On Error Resume Next

        Set f = fso.GetFolder(sf)

        For Each myFile In f.Files
            If Right(myFile, 11) = "outlook.exe" Then
            Range("A1").Value = myFile.Path
            Call outlook
            End
            End If
        Next
        For Each nsf In f.SubFolders
            Recursive nsf
        Next


    End Sub
    Sub outlook()
    Const PATH_TO_OUTLOOK = """C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\outlook.exe"""
    Const SHOW_MAXIMIZED = 3
    Const MINIMIZE = 1

    Dim oShell, oOutlook As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If oOutlook Is Nothing Then

        ' Open Outlook
        oShell.Run PATH_TO_OUTLOOK, SHOW_MAXIMIZED, False

        On Error Resume Next

        ' Grab a handle to the Outlook Application and minimize
        Set oOutlook = WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        WScript.Sleep (10000)
        oOutlook.ActiveExplorer.WindowState = SHOW_MAXIMIZED

        ' Loop on error to account for slow startup in which case the
        ' process and/or the main Outlook window is not available
          Err.Clear
          WScript.Sleep (10000)
          Set oOutlook = Nothing
          Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
          oOutlook.ActiveExplorer.WindowState = MINIMIZE


        Set oOutlook = Nothing
        Set oShell = Nothing
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: What is the purpose of finding the Outlook executable? If it's installed on the machine, all you need to do is `CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` and then set it to `.Visible`.

Comment: Maybe I'm going about this wrong, but I'm thinking that because different users may have different versions of office installed, and some may have 32-bit vs 64-bit, the executable would be in different locations.  The outlook routine that I posted works perfectly for my machine, but most likely not for every user that will be using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as Comintern commented -

```
Sub Test()

    Dim oOL As Object
    Dim ns As Object
    Dim fldr As Object

    Set oOL = CreateOL

    Set ns = oOL.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
    Set fldr = ns.GetDefaultFolder(6) 'olFolderInbox
    fldr.display

End Sub

Public Function CreateOL() As Object

    Dim oTmpOL As Object

    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Creating an instance of Outlook is different from Excel. '
    'There can only be a single instance of Outlook running,  '
    'so CreateObject will GetObject if it already exists.     '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set oTmpOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set CreateOL = oTmpOL

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CreateOL."
            Err.Clear
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: I have to admit that I'm not a vba expert first of all.  I've tried the code that you provided and the Outlook application opens for a few seconds and then closes.  The outlook routine that I originally posted works exactly how I want it to, but I need it to work for users with 32-bit or 64-bit office.  Maybe I went about it wrong, but I'm learning as I go.  Is there any way I can get the path for myFile to be passed to the outlook routine as the PATH_TO_OUTLOOK constant or anything similar?

Comment: I've updated the code so the inbox is visible once the code finishes.  To pass `myFile` to your Outlook routine you'll need to either set myFile as a variable visible to the whole module (declared at the top of the module), or update the your procedure name to `Sub Outlook(PATH_TO_OUTLOOK AS String)` and then when you call it use `Outlook myFile` or `CALL Outlook(myFile)` (the call keyword isn't required).

Comment: Thank you both so much for your help!  With your help, I was finally able to get it working the way I want it to.  I'm sure it's not as elaborate as it could be, but it's working!